# How to check for occurence of string within a list(of String)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, list, contains

I have this code:

```
Dim listCities As New List(Of String)
listCities.add("this is city London")
listCities.add("this city is called New York")
listCities.add("and another string with a city, this one Berlin")
```

When I try:

```
listCities.Contains("London")
```

It returns `false`, probably because there is no exact match.

How can I test if `listCities` contains a string, when that is a substring of a string within the list?

Obviously I prefer not to have to loop through all items in `listCities`

Comment: I was hoping for some sort of abstract function that does this (most effectively) for me, without me having to write my own loop.

Comment: There is no way to not loop over all items - even `LINQ` uses a loop internally.

Comment: @OneFineDay I know that, but like I mentioned: without me having to write my own loop and benefiting from what's already been made before :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [IEnumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) in this way

```
if listCities.Any(Function(x) x.IndexOf("London") > -1)) Then
   .. true ...
```

and if you have London spelled in different cases you could use the version of IndexOf that takes a `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` parameter

Comment: So my first comment is that this does not avoid looping through the occurrences of the strings in the list, it is simply shortcut notation of exactly the process of looping through the occurrences of the strings in the list. I don't think what the original poster is asking for is actually possible though.
I prefer the traditional few lines of a loop to do this, as it is far easier to understand after the fact. or better make an extension method to perform a function like this.

Comment: Yes Linq hides the loop but it is still there. In any case a loop somewhere is needed.

Comment: Given the OP's example, `Any` will not loop through *ALL* the strings in the list. It will return when it finds "London" in the 1st string and not look at any more of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve it with this:

```
listCities.Any(Function(x As String) x.Contains("London"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With *listCities* being a List, Contains compares the objects in your list with what you specify (in this case, a string). If you use Contains directly in a String object it will look for that specific string inside the string object.

So, what you need to do is iterate over your list and use Contains, using Any returns a boolean value:

```
listCities.Any(Function(cet) cet.Contains("London"))
```

It might be easier to see it like this

```
For Each city In From city1 In listCities Where city1.Contains("London")
       valueToReturn = True
       Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

This was what I was thinking, which allows easy reuse as well as understandable long term code format.

```
    Public Sub Test()
        Dim l As New List(Of String)
                     ' USAGE EXAMPLE
        Dim index As Integer = l.IndexOfContainsText("london")
    End Sub

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IndexOfContainsText(list As List(Of String), ContainsText As String) As Integer
        Dim out As Integer = -1
        For iQ As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1
            If list(iQ).Contains(ContainsText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                Return iQ
            End If
        Next
        Return out
    End Function
```